# Animate transformation from a line to a curve

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-animation, bezier

I encountered a problem when drawing an animated bounce curve. 
The code below allow the desired effect animating the line, however when curving i do not want to see the straight line. I had i done wrong with my code ? any comment or guidances are greatly appreciated.

Cheers

[image]

[image]

```
- (void)loadView
{
    //up Path
    upPath  = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(upPath, nil,startingDrawPointX,startingDrawPointY);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(upPath, nil, controlPoint.x, 100, endingDrawPointX, endingDrawPointY);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(upPath);

    //down Path
    downPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(downPath, nil,startingDrawPointX,startingDrawPointY);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(downPath, nil, controlPoint.x, 70, endingDrawPointX, endingDrawPointY);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(downPath);

    //mid Path
    midPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(midPath, nil,startingDrawPointX,startingDrawPointY);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(midPath, nil, controlPoint.x, controlPoint.y, endingDrawPointX, endingDrawPointY);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(midPath);


    //Create Shape

    shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
//  shapeLayer.path = midPath;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = nil;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = kDBrownTextColor.CGColor;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0;
//  shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleNonZero;
    [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    [self performSelector:@selector(startAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];

}

-(void)startAnimation
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    animation.duration = 1;
    animation.repeatCount = maxCount;
    animation.autoreverses = YES;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.fromValue = (__bridge id)downPath;
    animation.fromValue =(__bridge id)midPath;
    animation.toValue = (__bridge id)upPath;
    [shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animatePath"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out the lines with `CGPathCloseSubpath` - they are creating the straight lines you see